# Progress callback not updating during progress

Tags: javascript

I have written some code that reads a local text file and compresses it into a zip file using JSZip library.

I want to provide the user a progress bar as shown in this demo: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples/downloader.html

`zip.generateAsync()`method has a callback method but what happens is the file fully compresses then it send all the ticks at once at the end (check console output in code below using large enough file to cause some delay).

I can't understand what is blocking the callbacks until the process finishes.  Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```js
var statusEl = document.getElementById("status");

const fileSelector = document.getElementById("file-selector");

fileSelector.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  readFile(event);
});

function readFile(event) {
  statusEl.innerHTML = "Loading file";
  const fileList = event.target.files;
  console.log(fileList[0]);

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    statusEl.innerHTML = "Compressing file";
    zipFile(event.target.result);
  });
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileList[0]);
}

function zipFile(result) {
  var zip = new JSZip();
  zip.file("myfile.txt", result);

  zip
    .generateAsync(
      {
        type: "blob",
        compression: "DEFLATE",
        compressionOptions: {
          level: 6
        }
      },
      updateCallback
    )
    .then(function (content) {
      saveAs(content, "example.zip");
    });
}

function updateCallback(metaData) {
  statusEl.innerHTML = metaData.percent.toFixed(2) + " %";
  console.log(metaData.percent.toFixed(2) + " %");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.2/FileSaver.min.js"></script>

<label for="avatar">Choose a file:</label>

<input type="file"
       id="file-selector" name="file-selector" accept=".txt">
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: Btw, you should use `statusEl.textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: If I run the snippet in the question and snippets in both answers with the same file of 1.5Mb size, except that the progress messages start not from 0% but from around 52-54% (in all cases), I **can see the progress** in console. So what's the question again? Is the problem reproducible only locally?

Comment: In the question it will show all the ticks at the same time.  In the answers they start to update close to the end of the process.  It seems issue is it reads entire file instead of streaming it.  In the demo I linked its streaming it with ajax request and the bars show properly but im not sure how to stream a local file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript execution and page rendering are done in the same execution thread, which means that while your code is executing the browser will not be redrawing the page.

What you need to do is use the setTimeout(). Using these, there will be "spaces" in between your code execution in which the browser will get a chance to redraw the page.

**UPDATED**

1. You dont need to use FileReader, you can get the file from "onChange" on file selector.
2. added "streamFiles: true" into generateAsync options.

So, try this (It would be nice if your file is at least 8MB to clearly see the percentage):

```js
var statusEl = document.getElementById("status");

const fileSelector = document.getElementById("file-selector");

fileSelector.onchange = function() {
  var zip = new JSZip();
  zip.file("myfile.txt", this.files[0]);
 statusEl.innerHTML = "Compressing file";
 zip.generateAsync({
            type: "blob",
            compression: "DEFLATE",
            streamFiles: true,
            compressionOptions: {
                level: 6
            }
        },
        updateCallback
    )
    .then(function(content) {
        saveAs(content, "example.zip");
    });
};

function updateCallback(metaData) {
const percent = metaData.percent;

setTimeout(function() { 
   //console.log(percent);
   statusEl.textContent = percent.toFixed(2) + " %";
}, 10);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.2/FileSaver.min.js"></script>

<label for="avatar">Choose a file:</label>

<input type="file"
       id="file-selector" name="file-selector" accept=".txt">
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Would it be better for me to pass the File object to a worker and read it in the worker (not sure if thats possible) then the load might not block page draw?

Comment: Hi @Guerrilla, i updated the code and added some comments in the answer. Hope its that what you want. cheers.

Comment: Superb!  It works as I intended.  Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you need a [Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

```js
var statusEl = document.getElementById("status");

const fileSelector = document.getElementById("file-selector");

fileSelector.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  var blob = new Blob([
    document.querySelector('#worker1').textContent
  ], { type: "text/javascript" })

  var worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    statusEl.innerHTML = e.data;
    console.log(e.data)
  }
  worker.postMessage(event.target.files[0]);
});

function readFile(event) {
  statusEl.innerHTML = "Loading file";
  const fileList = event.target.files;
  console.log("qui", fileList[0]);

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    statusEl.innerHTML = "Compressing file";
    console.log(event.target.result instanceof ArrayBuffer)
    zipFile(event.target.result);
  });
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileList[0]);
}

function zipFile(result) {
  var zip = new JSZip();
  zip.file("myfile.txt", result);

  zip
    .generateAsync(
      {
        type: "blob",
        compression: "DEFLATE",
        compressionOptions: {
          level: 6
        }
      },
      updateCallback
    )
    .then(function (content) {
      saveAs(content, "example.zip");
    });
}

function updateCallback(metaData) {
  statusEl.innerHTML = metaData.percent.toFixed(2) + " %";
  console.log(metaData.percent.toFixed(2) + " %");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.2/FileSaver.min.js"></script>

<label for="avatar">Choose a file:</label>

<input type="file"
       id="file-selector" name="file-selector">
<div id="status"></div>

<script id="worker1" type="javascript/worker">
importScripts("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.5.0/jszip.min.js");

function readFile(file) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    zipFile(event.target.result);
  });
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

function zipFile(result) {
  var zip = new JSZip();
  zip.file("myfile.txt", result);

  zip
    .generateAsync(
      {
        type: "blob",
        compression: "DEFLATE",
        compressionOptions: {
          level: 6
        }
      },
      metaData => self.postMessage(metaData.percent.toFixed(2) + " %")
    )
    .then(function (content) {
      saveAs(content, "example.zip");
    });
}

self.onmessage = function(e) {
  readFile(e.data);
};
</script>
```

I tested it with a 70MB file and more or less it works. There is still an initial delay probably related to the read file time, if you find a solution to pipe the content from FileReader to JSZip...

Comment: I tried with a 1gb file and there is a long delay and then 3 seconds of progress.  I think you are right and it needs to stream, thats why I read it as array buffer but if i set type to arrayBuffer not blob it didn't work.  These are all the types it supports https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/generate_async.html (scroll to type).  Will any of those stream?